# JDBC Driver class not found: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have installed a third party java webservice which uses Oralce jdbc thin driver to write data into Oracle database. When i run this, i get the following error;

**JDBC Driver class not found: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver**

I have oracle installed and set classpath variable to following value:

*D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\classes12.jar;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\classes12.zip;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.zip;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar*

and path variable to following value;

*D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\classes12.jar;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\classes12.zip;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.zip*

Any suggestion why web service is not able to identify jdbc driver?

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you executing the web service?

Comment: How/where do you register the oracle driver (and copy/paste the *exact* error message and stacktrace you are getting)

Comment: @BalusC: I'm executing it was windows service. This is actually provided by third party vendor. I just updated the config file with database connection string and run the service

Comment: @nos: I got this error message: <log4j:message><![CDATA[JDBC Driver class not found: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver]]></log4j:message>.

Comment: Maybe the service isn't somehow picking up the classpath you have set(where/how did you set it). Perhaps it needs to be configured in a special way for your service.

Comment: @nos: I added classpath by creating new environment variable. I did refer service documentation and there are no special instructions regarding oracle drivers. Infact the set up is working fine in test environment. I have this problem in staging environment.

Comment: It's hard to post an answer as long as we know nothing about that web service. At least, you should not confuse `PATH` with `CLASSPATH`. The operating system platform-specific `PATH` environment variable has **nothing** to do with classpath. It should represent a collection of disk file system paths where the operating system has to look for executabeles. The Java-specific `CLASSPATH` environment variable is only used by Java and it represent a collection of disk file system paths where Java has to look for classes.

Comment: @BalusC: Thank you. I think i did mistake by adding *.zip files in path variable and this seems to have confused the system. I removed non-exe from path variable and added them correctly to classpath variable and web service was able to access oracle db. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know 2 ways of turning Java app into Windows service and both do not use `CLASSPATH`. One is [Java Service Wrapper by Tanuki Software](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/). This tool uses `wrapper.conf` where you can show directories with `.jar` libraries:

```
# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=c:\jars\*
wrapper.java.classpath.2=myservice.jar
```

Second tool I know is [JSL: Java Service Launcher](http://jslwin.sourceforge.net/). In this tool there is `jsl.ini` where you put command line to run your server. It can use java with `-cp` option to show location of `.jar` libraries:

```
[defines]
MY_LIBS=d:\jars\*
AXIS_LIBS=d:\axis2-1.5.4\lib\*
CLASSPATH=.;%MY_LIBS%;%AXIS_LIBS%
export = CLASSPATH
...

[java]
...
cmdline = -Dfile.encoding=utf8 -cp %CLASSPATH% example.my.server
```

In both configuration you can use `*` to add all `.jar` files or you can show those files one by one (just like in `CLASSPATH`).

At first you should know what Windows is trying to execute. Check it in the service properties page. Then try to localize its configuration. If it uses one of tools I know then you know what to change. Other tools probably have similar configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:
Download ojdbc.jar

add ojdbc6.jar to deployment assembly.
Right click on project->properties->select deployment assembly->click on 'Add'
->select 'Archives from File System'->browse to the folder where ojdbc6.jar is saved.->add the jar->click finish->Apply/OK.

Method 2:

if you want to add ojdbc.jar to your maven dependencies you follow this link:
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/
.
.
Even if you're using a maven project it is not necessary to add ojdbc to maven dependencies(method 2), method 1 (adding directly to deployment assembly) works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the ojdbc jar file (make sure you are using the correct one because depending on java version you may need to choose a different one).

use ojdbc14.jar for Java 1.4 
use ojdbc5.jar for Java 1.5
ojdbc6.jar for Java 1.6
here is linke where you can download ojdbc6.jar file
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add the jdbc jar to your server classpath. if tomcat, rigth-click on your Project->run as->run configurations, click on classpath and add your jdbc jar in Add external jars option

Answer (score 0):

add ojdbc-6.jar to your lib directory of tomcat installation. Maven will downlowd this jar for you in .m2 directory, but you need to have this jar in tomcat lib as well.