# trying to connect to sql database and driver cannot be found

Tags: java, sql, oracle, driver, ojdbc

i am using netbeans to write a java application. I need to connect to an sql database and i get this error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

I use maven project and I added the dependency : ojdbc14

```
  try {     //load database driver
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger("Driver not found");
            System.out.println(ex);
            System.out.println("error");
        }
```

What can I do to fix this problem ? I am new to java and I do not know much

Comment: You are connecting to an Oracle database or a SQL Server database?                                                                                                                                                                                                                            In general, when connecting to Oracle database you will need to have the Oracle ODBC driver installed, which are not part of standard windows installation.  I'm not sure how this plays with java, but you may need to install the Oracle database client in order to obtain the appropriate driver.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the driver on to your computer. Here is an answer
[JDBC Driver class not found: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478454/jdbc-driver-class-not-found-oracle-jdbc-oracledriver)

Answer (score 1):

I am just wondering: You said ojdbc14? That was the oracle jdbc driver to be used with Java 1.4.

I would suggest to use the latest version which is ojdbc8:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.jdbc/ojdbc8

That is of April 2019 and not of 2009 (ojdbc14).

Maybe even this information of 2016 is useful:
https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides

Comment: My problem is that I click add dependency search for ojdbc from oracle and it only shows ojdbc14 , Ojdbc6 or 8 are only from other sources available!

Comment: yes, Oracle wants you to create an account and accept the license agreement. You have to do this either when downloading and installing the driver manually (as suggested by Narayan in the local answer or when adding the Oracle Maven Site.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the JDBC driver from [OTN](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html) and use it too.